# To protect your application you must either upgrade to Sprockets version "3. heroku rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting an error while deploying to heroku:

```
security vulnerability has been detected in your application.
remote:  !     To protect your application you must take action. Your application
remote:  !     is currently exposing its credentials via an easy to exploit directory
remote:  !     traversal.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To protect your application you must either upgrade to Sprockets version "3.
```

I tried to write bundle update sprockets in console but got an error:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

I tried to install

```
gem install json -v '1.8.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

But got an error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180704-2814-12i6evl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                         ^
generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                         ^
generator.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

---

I also tried to set in my `envoronments/production.rb` 
`config.assets.compile = false` but still the same error - can't push to heroku

Comment: this is my gemfile: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13bz3F0h6a89Yxd8lXbWgeBY33DUeEM0pml6zAQohQ38/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: could you upload your `Gemfile.lock`? pastebin should work

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary solution:

Change `heroku/ruby` to `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#v186` using the command `heroku buildpacks`.

You should regain deploy ability and a window to fix the issue.

[source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1437)